# how this pointer arithmetic works

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have couple of snippets:

```
main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,45};

    printf("%p\n", a); /* as expected print address of first element of array */
    printf("%p\n", a+1); /* expecting it to print address after this array ends as type of a is int[4] and pointer arithmetic says size of type is added to it, i.e. 16 bytes but its printing address of second element of array a, 
}
```

Similarly this snippet:

```
int main()
{   
    int *a[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
 
    printf("arr0=%d\n", *a+0);
    printf("arr1=%d\n", *a+1);
    printf("arr2=%d\n", *a+2);
    printf("arr3=%d\n", *a+3);
    printf("arr4=%d\n", *a+4);
 
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
0
4
8
12
16
```

But since pointer size is 8 bytes, and as every member of this array is pointer then why pointer size is not adding up to produce ?

```
0
8
16
24
32
```

Comment: is there something like pointer type vs pointee type?

Comment: Second snippet is UB, you are printing pointer type with `%d` (`a` is array of *pointers*)

Comment: `(*a)` if of type of `int*`. So the pointer arithmetic on it will perform in units of size of `int`. `*a+x` is equivalent to `(*a)+x`. That is a value of `a[0]` plus `x*sizeof(int)`. This snippet is quite confusing, I must admit.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now, I was missing the pointe that "pointer arithmetic on it will perform in units of size of int" that is type of object pointer pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

When an array in used in an expression, in most cases it will decay to a pointer to its first element.

Taking this example:

```
printf("%p\n", a+1);
```

First `a` decays from type `int[4]` to `int *` so it points to the first element of the array.  Adding 1 to this causes it to point to the second element of the array.

Had you done this:

```
printf("%p\n", &a+1);
```

The `&` operator is one of the few cases where an array does not decay, so `&a` has type `int (*)[4]` i.e. a pointer to an array of size 4.  Adding 1 to this results in a pointer pointing to just after the end of the array.

Comment: I don't think it was the question... Was it?

Answer (score 0):

Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in the first code snippet in the call of `printf` the array `a` is converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `int *`

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,45};
//...
printf("%p\n", a+1)
```

Due to the pointer arithmetic the value of the expression `a + 1` is incremented relative to the expression `a` by `sizeof( int )` that is equal to `4` in your system.

In the second code snippet the expression `*a` that is the same as `a[0]` has the type `int *` So the value of the expression `*a + 1` is also incremented by the value `sizeof( int )`.

Pay attention to that using the conversion specifier %d with a pointer expression in statements like this

```
printf("arr0=%d\n", *a+0);
```

has undefined behavior.  You have to write

```
printf("arr0=%p\n", ( void * )( *a+0 ));
```

Comment: In fact, integer arithmetic on invalid pointers (and `a` is an array of invalid pointers) is UB as well, strictly speaking.

Comment: I think he didn't really intend for `*a+0` to be a pointer. That was probably supposed to be an `int` array rather than `int*`.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure.. looks like the OP is aware of it "*...But since pointer size is 8 bytes, and as every member of this array is pointer..*", but got lost in the way.